# get the last id of the query with pdo php

Tags: mysql, pdo

Hello friends of the forum
I have a question with $db->lastInsertId().

$db->lastInsertId(); refers to the last id inserted in the database or is the id used in that query.

thank you and best regards.

Comment: Well it is pretty clear in the documentation. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: Well it turns out that the documentation is not that clear. it's the id generated by in the last insert query you executed.

Comment: Many thanks "Your common sense".
the documentation is not that clear.  a greeting